# Hiding Empty Parent Nodes in Hierarchial Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query shows hierarchial sturcture. But when some of the child values are filtered, most of the parent returns empty and making focus on the child difficult.

In need to eliminate parent rows which has no child.

```
Select
 Obejctid,
 Parentid,
 Name
From parent_table
UNION
Select
 Objcetid,
 Parentid,
 Name
From child_table
Prior
 Objcetid=Parentobjectid
```

Comment: Could you post a data sample? Preferably here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21

Comment: @Zakaria The sample data should be posted in the question. A link to a fiddle would also be useful but links break so the main focus should be to ensure that the question stays relevant in the future.